# Tap on uibutton inside imageview, inside scrollview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

In my application I have got a `UIScrollview` in which the user can view an map (.PNG) a `UIImageView`. The `UIScrollView` is used to handle the panning and scrolling around the map.

I want to user to be able to 'add' extra points of interest (buttons) on the map when they touch it, to do this I have added a Tap Listener onto the `UIScrollView`;

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture:)];

[myScrollview addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

When a tap is registered I create a UIButton and add this button the `UIImageView` inside of the `UIScrollView`:

```
   [plattegrondImageview addSubview:plattegrondPunt];
```

That way the element scrolls nicely along with the image (stays in place on the given coordinates). So far so good.

Yet, now I want the user to be able to tap the 'button' (and then open a Popover screen to enter a comment for example).

I have added a target to the button to listen for a tap:

```
[poi addTarget:self action:@selector(puntTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now for the problem:

Whenever the user tap's on the button, the selector (puntTap) is correctly fired, but also the main tap gesture on the `UIScrollview` is fired.

So not only a `popover` view is opened, but also an extra `UIButton` element is placed on to the screen.

Theoretically it's logical that the `UIScrollview` also registers the tap, but in this case that's unwanted behavior. Whenever the users taps on a `UIButton` inside of the `scrollview`, the `scrollview` itself shouldn't respond.

To visualize the layers:

-> `UIScrollview`

-----> `UIImageView`

----------> `UIButton`

I have already enabled the following properties for the scrollview;

```
myScrollview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
myScrollview.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
myScrollview.delaysContentTouches = YES;
```

I guess I could do something like a hittest (with the Tap Gesture of the `UIScrollview`), to check if it isn't a button that is tapped - But maybe somebody has got a 'cleaner' solution?

(If anything is unclear about the way I have setup the screen, please say so)

**Summarized**: When the user taps on the `UIButton`, the `GestureRecognizer` of the `scrollview` also fires!

Answer (score 1):

you could set userInteractionEnabled for the scrollView to False/No in uibutton touchesbegan and re-enable it in uibutton touchesEnded.

another, perhaps better option would be set the uibutton exclusiveTouch property to YES.

Edit: just seen your comment above. It sounds like the touch is being propagated to your uibutton from the scrollview. In which case you might have to check the touch co-ordinates in scrollview and only add the new buttons if a button doesn't exist in that vicinity (probably a good id idea anyway?). I assume you are storing the button locations as it is so simply check against the current list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The touch indeed seems to be propagated from the scrollview (exclusivetouch has no visible effect) - I'm now exactly doing what you propose with a HitTest, although I'm doing it on the fly (not against my own array which is probably a better idea (performance))

Answer (score 1):

Just an **idea** (not tested):

If you want to stick to your GesutureRecognizers, than try to use another one on the button, instead of setting a target directly. So you can set the first recognizer to cancel the other one:

`- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`

**Another idea** is to overwrite `hitTest:` by subclassing `UIScrollView` to check, if a button is touched.

Comment: Thanx! The first idea sounds like an option, but when doing so I'll also lose the standard touch events from the button I believe (TouchUpInside etc) - I have implemented your second idea (although not subclassing it) - I'm now hittesting, inside the tap recognizer of the scrollview. When the hitted view is of a type UIButton I cancel the further process of that tapgesture (and my Button takes over the action)

Comment: yes, you would need to trigger the button states within the gesturerecognizer to preserve them.

Answer (score 0):

Set this property for the button.

```
myButton.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

so that it will prevent touch from migrating to view beneath it.

Comment: That, unfortunately, doesn't seem to do the trick, the scrollview/tap still fires. I have set it on the button, but its actually the view 'above' which also gets the touch (tap) (The button is the view last down)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by our incomplete implementation of the responder chain.

As you have registered `UIScrollView` for `tapGesture` so it will be handling all the tap gestures that are performed on it. But, it will also be handling tap gestured that are performed on its `subviews` but not handled by themselves. In your case button will fall under subview category as its immediate `superview`(`imageView`) is not responding to these event so the touch event will go to scrollview.

But currently, `button` is only registered for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` type of touch event and not for all touch events so the other `UIControlEvents` will be passed to its responding `superview`, in this case `UIScrollView`.

So, if *`button handles all types of touch event`* then it will not ask its `superview` to handle them.